# Parse Dashboard doesn't load view

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-platform

I'm working on nodejs/Parse server it works fine on localy but when I tried to deploy my server to heroku I found that the dashboard didn't load the DB data (dasboard display loading spinner untel bring Time out). like this:
[image]

here is my server dashboard instance:

```
let dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
    apps: [
        {
            appName: env.PARSE_APPNAME,
            appId: env.PARSE_APPID',
            masterKey: env.PARSE_MASTERKEY,
            clientKey: env.PARSE_CLIENTKEY,
            javascriptKey: env.PARSE_JAVASCRIPTKEY,
            restApiKey: env.PARSE_RESTAPIKEY,
            graphQLServerURL: `${host}:${port}${mountPathGraphQL}`,//
            serverURL: `${host}:${port}${mountPath}`,//
            iconName: env.DASH_ICON || "logo.png"
        },
    ],
    iconsFolder: "icons",
    users: [
        {
            user: env.DASH_USER,
            pass: env.DASH_PASS'
        }
    ]
}, { allowInsecureHTTP: true });
```

and api call:

```
let mountPathDash = env.PARSE_MOUNT_DASH || '/dashboard'
app.use(mountPathDash, dashboard);
```

I have also prepared Procfile file contains:

```
web: node server.js
```

on my heroku log:

> 2021-02-22T14:17:23.931913+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/dashboard/" host=nplboost.herokuapp.com
> request_id=c4244237-7d6a-4886-9f8e-c7190e9846ed fwd="196.203.182.5"
> dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=712 protocol=https
> 2021-02-22T14:17:25.273889+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/dashboard/bundles/dashboard.bundle.js"
> host=nplboost.herokuapp.com
> request_id=97de1799-19e7-43c8-856c-e22383a7c645 fwd="196.203.182.5"
> dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=239 protocol=https
> 2021-02-22T14:17:25.664996+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json"
> host=nplboost.herokuapp.com
> request_id=f220e66b-af01-4169-98f3-28c06f369859 fwd="196.203.182.5"
> dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=151 protocol=https
> 2021-02-22T14:31:29.918524+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/dashboard/apps/NplBoost/migrations" host=nplboost.herokuapp.com
> request_id=a2da7714-0752-48dd-a1a3-4fb0dc2f1047 fwd="196.203.182.5"
> dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=200 bytes=712
> protocol=https 2021-02-22T14:31:29.922030+00:00 heroku[router]:
> at=info method=GET path="/dashboard/bundles/sprites.svg"
> host=nplboost.herokuapp.com
> request_id=ea1e7dde-2270-47c6-8335-410808724bec fwd="196.203.182.5"
> dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=238
> protocol=https 2021-02-22T14:31:29.922877+00:00 heroku[router]:
> at=info method=GET path="/dashboard/" host=nplboost.herokuapp.com
> request_id=88a0e442-734a-4885-95e7-9d0c3cb00c41 fwd="196.203.182.5"
> dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=17ms status=304 bytes=168
> protocol=https 2021-02-22T14:31:29.930207+00:00 heroku[router]:
> at=info method=GET path="/dashboard/appicons/logo.png"
> host=nplboost.herokuapp.com
> request_id=1dec56f5-683c-4cef-a800-81061eb0b56b fwd="196.203.182.5"
> dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=18008
> protocol=https

My parse configuration:

```
var parseServer = new ParseServer({
    cloud: __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    databaseURI: databaseUri,
    appName: env.PARSE_APPNAME,
    appId: env.PARSE_APPID,
    masterKey: env.PARSE_MASTERKEY,
    clientKey: env.PARSE_CLIENTKEY,
    javascriptKey: env.PARSE_JAVASCRIPTKEY,
    restApiKey: env.PARSE_RESTAPIKEY,
    fileKey: env.PARSE_FILEKEY,
    webhookKey: env.PARSE_WEBHOOKKEY,
    dotNetKey: env.PARSE_DOTNETKEY,
    serverURL: `${host}:${port}${mountPath}`,
    publicServerURL: `${host}:${port}${mountPath}`,
    verifyUserEmails: false, 
    emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration: 24 * 60 * 60,
    preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail: false,
    emailAdapter: !hasSMTPInfo ? undefined : {
        module: 'parse-smtp-template',
        options: {
            port: env.EMAIL_PORT,
            host: env.EMAIL_HOST,
            user: env.EMAIL_USER,
            password: env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
            fromAddress: env.EMAIL_FROMADDRESS,
            template: env.EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
            templatePath: env.EMAIL_TEMPLATEPATH
        }
    },
    accountLockout: {
        duration: 10, // threshold policy setting determines the number of failed sign-in attempts that will cause a user account to be locked. Set it to an integer value greater than 0 and less than 1000.
        threshold: 6, // duration policy setting determines the number of minutes that a locked-out account remains locked out before automatically becoming unlocked. Set it to a value greater than 0 and less than 100000.
    },
    passwordPolicy: {
        validatorPattern: /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})/, // enforce password with at least 8 char with at least 1 lower case, 1 upper case and 1 digit
        //validatorCallback: (password) => { return validatePassword(password) },
        validationError: 'Password must contain at least 8 chars, 1 lowercase, 1 lowercase and 1 digit.', // optional error message to be sent instead of the default "Password does not meet the Password Policy requirements." message.
        doNotAllowUsername: true, // optional setting to disallow username in passwords
        maxPasswordAge: 90, // optional setting in days for password expiry. Login fails if user does not reset the password within this period after signup/last reset.
        maxPasswordHistory: 5, // optional setting to prevent reuse of previous n passwords. Maximum value that can be specified is 20. Not specifying it or specifying 0 will not enforce history.
        resetTokenValidityDuration: 24 * 60 * 60, // expire after 24 hours
    },
});
```

with my Server URL is `nplboost.herokuapp.com:xxxx/parse`

Comment: Could you check if there is any error message in your web browser console or any request failing in your web browser network tab?

Comment: ok, 5mins after connecting to dashboard I found on console `POST https://nplboost.herokuapp.com:51222/parse/serverInfo net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` and I found on heroku log `WARNING, Unable to connect to 'https://nplboost.herokuapp.com:51222/parse'. Cloud code and push notifications may be unavailable`

Comment: Is this address right https://nplboost.herokuapp.com:51222/parse/serverInfo ? Is your Parse Server properly running?

Comment: ok I have updated my rep with my parse server configuration

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?